# The very basics of french accents

Tags: accents

How do I write this sentence "Le comportement de l’homme rationnel devant le risque: critique des postulats et axiomes de l’école Américaine" in French in LaTex?

I need to know the basic, as I have not written any french accents in LaTex before?

Also I am using TexMaker and here is my preamble:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}

    % Packages
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[french]{babel}
```

**EDIT:** This is the problem I am having now:

[image]

The Title References has accents.

Comment: The accented `e`s are obtained with `\'e`.

Comment: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and just enter the sentence, with `babel` support for french language?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I tried installing the package after your suggestion, but it is saying "undefined control sequence".

Comment: @user36829: Yes, typo of mine: I meant `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: Another option is swapping out for the LuaTeX or XeTeX engines that support unicode natively. Just call `xelatex` (or `lualatex`) instead of `pdflatex`.

Comment: @user36829 Références is perfect French (I believe :-) ). It seems as if you do not want to have your document in French so do not load that `babel` option. If you want to change the language for parts of your document, please read the `babel` documentation. If you just need this one sentence, just leave the option away. It will look good with utf8. However, if you want to do it the French way for this example (I would do... I love typographical differences all over the globe), just type `risque~: ` as reccomended by Bernard in the comment below my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the package `inputenc` (and the option for the encoding of your editor) for this and you should type ' instead of ` for the apostrophes (this last point could be some issue of copy/pasting on my system...).

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % my editor is set to use utf8 and this would be my recommendation for most cases

\begin{document}
Le comportement de l'homme rationnel devant le risque: critique des postulats et axiomes de l'école Américaine
\end{document}
```

If you want the colon to be separated a bit from the prior word, you must load `\usepackage[french]{babel}`. Will be helpful in any case, I guess.

[image]

Comment: This will lead to absolute nonsense if the editor is not set up to to use the right encoding. The matching encoding of editor and option should be mentioned. Of course, utf8 would be preferred.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi This works! Another small question BTW. How do I write the Spanish squiggle accent like for el nino?

Comment: \user36829 This is called *tilde* and can be written as `\~n or ñ ` in my MWE above. (btw. that are really basics. You should read some introduction to LaTeX to get a better start here.)

Comment: For some reason I am having accents on the title of my "References" section.

Comment: @user36829 Please kick out all the unneeded packages in your code above and insert the issue, you are seeing. I can not guess why you get accents (which ones?) on the ñ in "References" (which has none in Spanish or French).

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: If there's only need for one sentence in French language, it's not really necessary to concern about the French typography rules for a `:`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer True. But I do not know if it is just this sentence. I did not want to open the topic `\begin{otherlanguage}{french}` and so on; that's why I did not put it to my MWE.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Agreed. I did not meant it as criticism! Perhaps you should add to your answer, that the used editor must apply the `utf8` encoding.

Comment: If you do not want to use `babel` for a short piece of text, you can use the following rules: before `!?,»` and after `«` add a thin unbreakable space (`\,`). Before `:`, add an unbreakable space (`~`).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer not taken as such. No worries. About utf8, I just added some remarks due to Johannes' comment. I hope that's enough.

Comment: If I remove the babel code I get this "! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option french yet." What does this mean?

Comment: @user36829 compile again and it should be gone. If not, remove the `.aux` file from your main folder. The auxiliary file thinks that you are in French mode, but it can't find that option as you have deleted it.